# Android app for ledger-cli

Tags: android, command-line, csv, accounting

I want to use the [Ledger command line accounting software](http://ledger-cli.org). Are there any android apps I can use to generate CSV files of expenses when I'm away from home, which can then be imported into Ledger?

Comment: One usually writes Ledger files with a text editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having played around with ledger more, I've opted to encrypt my .ledger.journal with GnuPG then upload to cloud storage.

I can then sync it with my android phone, decrypt using [openkeychain](https://www.openkeychain.org) and edit it using [jotterpad](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jotterpad.x&hl=en_GB&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Djotterpad&pcampaignid=APPU_1_fTaZWZDmCYvLgAac9YbYDw), my text editor of choice.

Comment: What is the point of having the full ledger file on Android when you can't run any reports and check the validity of entered data?

Answer (score 0):

Many financial apps support CSV export. I have been using, and contributing to, [Money Manager Ex for Android](http://android.moneymanagerex.org/). It is an Open Source app and supports export to CSV and QIF formats.

I also wrote a Python [library](https://gitlab.com/alensiljak/moneymanagerexlib) for reading the database, so export to CSV can happen outside the app itself, either on a PC or on a mobile device.

There are plenty of tools that will convert CSV, or other formats, to ledger syntax, which you can append to your book file.

Answer (score 0):

You may use PortDB.apk and export tables to CSV. I sync the export folder with MEGASync, my journal file is acessible by 3 devices (KaliLinux, Windows7 and Android) https://apkpure.com/br/portodb-database/com.portofarina.portodb